# Comments(/*...*/) longer than one line

Tags: c, filesystems, comments

I am supposed to count the `/*...*/` comments in a file and I was wondering if this `code` is right or am I missing something out?

**My Code**

```
void commentsLongerThanOneLine(FILE* inputStream, FILE* outputStream) {
int count = 0, c, state = 1;

    while ((c = fgetc(inputStream) != EOF)) {
        switch (state) {
            case 1: switch (c) {
                case '/': state = 2; break;
            }
            break;

            case 2: switch (c) {
                case '/': state = 3; break;
                case '*': state = 4; break;
                default: state = 1;
            }
            break;
            case 3: switch (c) {
                case '\n': state = 1; break;
                default: state = 4; count++;
            }
            break;
            case 4:switch (c) {
                case'*': if (c == '\n') count++; break;
                default:  state = 4; if (c == '\n') count++;
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(outputStream, "Comments longer than one line: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: That's what testing is for.

Comment: why are you counting // comments when your aim is to only count /* ...*/ comments

Comment: Can't you just compile the program, and run it. If there is an error while compiling, or you get unexpected output, the program doesn't work.

Comment: Compile it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php). this is a free online compiler for C.

Comment: If you replaced the state numbers by constants names, it would be easier to read and for you to maintain.